# How can I convert erb to html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, templating

Imagine in rails I have `@template` that is an instance of `ActionTemplate::View`.

Question is: How can I convert `@template` whose @template.source is `<%= "hello from erb" %>` to `hello from erb`?? thanks

Comment: Maybe `render @template`, never seen an instance of template used in any practical sense though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
ERB.new(@template.source).result
```

[ERB#new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new)

Answer (score 4):

Well... messing around with `ActionView::Template.new` outside of Rails is not really recommended. You need a ton of stuff setup beforehand ([init](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/565c1b0a0772ac6cf91c77e9285806f7b028614c/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb#L142) and [render](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/565c1b0a0772ac6cf91c77e9285806f7b028614c/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb#L142))

If you do want to just use [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html), then go with this example

```
require 'erb'

x = 42
template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  The value of x is: <%= x %>
EOF
puts template.result(binding)
```

And, you can use  Kyle's answer to go from your template to ERB.