# Parsing HTML file that ERB template creates

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am new to ruby on rails. I understand that I can parse html documents using nokogiri. I need to write the html that the erb template creates to a file. Then I will parse that with nokogiri.

I can view the html that is created via Inspect Element in my web browser. This is all well and good, but I am at a loss as to how I can write this HTML to a readable / parse-able file in my local project?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572396/how-can-i-convert-erb-to-html

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one

ERB.new(@template.source).result